# Print standard deviation of column in file using R/awk

Tags: linux, r, awk

I have a file with a column of numbers

```
4.685
5.440
5.751
4.685
3.979
```

In my shell script I would like to interrogate many of these files and get the standard deviation and mean

I can achieve mean using awk easily enough
`awk '{sum+=$1} END { print sum/NR}' file`

When using awk for standard deviation
`awk '{x[NR]=$0; s+=$0} END{a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/NR); print sd}' file`

I get `0.625`. This number differs from excel which gives me `0.699`. I have since discovered I can execute R from the command line to print out the sd:
`R -q -e "x <- read.csv('file', header = F);  sd(x[ , 1])"`

However, this gives a slightly messy output

```
[1] 4.908
\> 
\>
```

Can I adjust the R command to print out only the number without resorting to head and cut/awk?

Also what is wrong with my awk code for extracting standard deviation?

Comment: I can't comment on the R command line portion, but I can say that Excel's standard deviation and your awk standard deviation differ because you divide by `N` (the number of observations), and Excel probably divides by `N - 1`.

Comment: R divides by N-1. See `? sd`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what's wrong with your awk, but for the `R` command, you might find that `write` helps:

```
R -q -e "x<- read.csv('file.csv',header=FALSE)[,1] ; write(sd(x),file='result.txt')"
```